# Need to attempt brute-force passcode on my time server

Tags: brute-force

I have a Krontek KT2000 GPS SNTP time server.  For some unexplained reason it has decided there is now a passcode required for Telnet access.  It was NIB and never had one, and I had accessed it a few times including setting an IP address for the network.  There is no backdoor or "master passcode".  The OS is embedded in a flash-coded system incorporated in the ethernet receptacle (see https://whrl.pl/RgwrCV for more detail).

On a suggestion in that forum thread, I checked the superuser article and found the Telnet Scripting Tool to look promising.  Now my coding experience started in Fortran on an IBM 1620, and pretty much ended with work in VB-DOS in 2005, and I don't want to learn a new language for what is largely a curiosity item.  I could give it away but unless this can be sorted, it's a small paperweight.

I'm about as far from a super-user as it is possible to get, but figured joing and posting here  might attract a workable reply from one.  Apologies if I shouldn't be here.

I tried TST from a Basic (yeah, soo last millennium) SHELL command to initiate TST primed with a test script and hopefully directing some output to see why it didn't do anything sensible.  No output of any sense.  The idea behind using Basic (apart from the fact I remember most of it) was to easily construct the four-character passcode strings for the TST script.  Case-insensitive, 36^4.

So far, no recognisable response from the time server.

Any suggestions for someone out of his depth